Why is Neovim, vim, lunarvim, every vim based terminal editor is very slow
First thing first, I am on ubuntu 23.10, with nvidia RTX 2060 core i5-8400 24 GB RAM and OS on SSD, using "oh my fish" as shell but tried on good old bash too. neovim config is done by lazyvim.
But All vim based editors are slow for me, Keystrokes take seconds to registers, sometime it doesn't register at all until i smash few more keys and then it registers all the keys at once, the command window that pops up after pressing ":" to quit vim and neovim are especially very slow and that happens everytime, like if i have to quit vim/neovim pressing ":wq" doesn't render until i press arrow key, sometimes only w appear sometime nothing. tree sitter on neovim is also very sluggish, takes few seconds to over a minute to go inside a directory which is on ssd and have only 4-5 files,
VScode and even android studio runs smoothly,
I have seen this issue in tmux too.
I have also tried starting the terminal with "launch using discrete graphic card" and issue is still there, what could be issue any ideas ?

Do you happen to have a ~/.vimrc file? What's in it?

@Heptite
I had it, i also tried removing it, and it still was slow, i uninstalled vim, neovim, lunarvim, everything also removed all of their config and even the vim history, even on fresh install it was extremely slow.
I did some research and changed my terminal app, since i was on ubuntu i was using the default gnome-terminal, i switched to alacritty and now it is working fine.
Probably their was some compatibility issue with hardware acceleration, as i was using proprietery nvidia driver on RTX 2060.
